# JS Array.from() log input values to the console

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

How do you get HTML input number values from multiple inputs after using Array.from() on a NODElist so that you can log to the console and see the values in the array?

```js
let ips = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let arr_ips = Array.from(ips);
console.log(arr_ips);
```

```html
<input type="number" value=100>
<input type="number" value=200>
<input type="number" value=600>
```

console result is the following,looking for the values only:
(3) [input, input, input]
0: input
1: input
2: input
length: 3
**proto**: Array(0)

Comment: You mean `console.log(arr_ips.map(ip => ip.value))`?

Answer (score 0):

With a second parameter passed, the mapper function, you can extract the `.value` from each:

```js
let ips = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let arr_ips = Array.from(ips, input => input.value);
console.log(arr_ips);
```

```html
<input type="number" value=100>
<input type="number" value=200>
<input type="number" value=600>
```